# Having Asking for Group By clause and not allowing it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to include a selection for the MAX date range in my where clause. I am using Having to bring it in, but it errors out saying that `"Column 'dbo.PURCHLINE.PURCHID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."` But it won't let me group, throwing other errors. Maybe i'm approaching this wrong. Essentially, I need to get the latest date in in a set of columns for this query:

```
Select 
    PURCHLINE.PURCHID as 'PO'
    ,SUBSTRING(Cast(Max(VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR.DELIVERYDATE) as varChar), 0, 12) as 'DeliveryDate'
    ,PURCHLINE.QTYORDERED as 'QtyOrdered'
FROM dbo.PURCHLINE 
    INNER JOIN dbo.INVENTTABLE 
        ON dbo.PURCHLINE.ITEMID = dbo.INVENTTABLE.ITEMID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.INVENTITEMGROUP 
        ON dbo.INVENTTABLE.ITEMGROUPID = dbo.INVENTITEMGROUP.ITEMGROUPID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.INVENTPOSTING 
        ON dbo.INVENTITEMGROUP.ITEMGROUPID = ITEMRELATION 
    INNER JOIN dbo.PURCHTABLE 
        ON dbo.PURCHLINE.PURCHID = dbo.PURCHTABLE.PURCHID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.LEDGERTABLE 
        ON LEDGERACCOUNTID = ACCOUNTNUM 
    INNER JOIN VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR 
        on VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR.PURCHID = PURCHLINE.PURCHID
WHERE
    dbo.PURCHLINE.PURCHSTATUS = 3 --open Order
    AND dbo.PURCHLINE.PURCHASETYPE = 3 --Purchase Order
    AND dbo.PURCHLINE.DIMENSION IN (@department)
    AND INVENTACCOUNTTYPE = 0 --Purchase Packing Slip
    AND PURCHLINE.DIMENSION2_ = @division
    HAVING Max(VENDPACKINGSLIPJOUR.DELIVERYDATE) between @start and @end
```

Comment: What did the group by clause look like that generated the error? Was it simply "GROUP BY PURCHLINE.PURCHID, SUBSTRING (...), PURCHLINE.QTYORDERED" ?

Comment: Group By PURCHLINE.PURCHID I tried that first, and it says Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'.
The Group By was after the HAVING clause

Comment: Did you take out the "AS PO" and "AS DELIVERYDATE" etc parts when you copied over the select fields into the group by fields? Could you show the code that generated the error?

Comment: Are you sure grouping is the right answer here?  Grouping by `PURCHID` will give you one result per value, and grouping by `QTYORDERED` seems odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an aggregate, so you'll need to group on the nonaggregate fields:

```
GROUP BY
     PURCHLINE.PURCHID
    ,PURCHLINE.QTYORDERED
```

This goes before the `HAVING` clause.